# Staking rewards for collator services

Tags: staking, collator, pallet-staking

**How to add Staking rewards for collator services for Node operators ?**

Answer (score 1):

Review the code of how existing parachains have already added that feature or are in the process of doing so and then abide by their licensing requirements if you make use of their code or the approach they took, such as:

- Moonbeam's parachain-staking pallet [here](https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/tree/master/pallets/parachain-staking)
- Nodle's parachain-staking pallet (pull request) [here](https://github.com/NodleCode/chain/pull/585/files)

Comment: Note that Kilt, Mangata Finance, and Zeitgeist may also be using Moonbeam's parachain-staking pallet