# Pallets needed for staking

Tags: staking, pallet-staking

Can anyone please explain what are the different types of pallets we need to add to a runtime in order to integrate staking into our runtime?

Answer (score 9):

If you want nominated proof of stake (**NPoS**) for validator staking of a standalone chain then you may extend the [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) by adding these further pallets from the Substrate repository:

- **pallet-staking**, **pallet-staking-reward-curve**, and **pallet-session** to configure bonding, inflation, and frequency of validator staking reward distribution to nominators
- **pallet-treasury** to send slashed funds to
- **pallet-collective** and **pallet-membership** so the super-majority of the council may cancel slashing

If you want delegated proof of stake (**DPoS**) for collator staking of a parachain then extend the Cumulus-based [substrate-parachain-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template), see the answer [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2902/83), which shows parachains that have implemented custom solutions using:

- **parachain-staking** pallet that improves upon the functionality of the Cumulus **collator-selection** pallet by allowing delegation of stake to a list of collator candidates

Comment: Hi. Which function that calculate the amount of staking and determine candidates for the block producers?