# What is the core functionality (pallets) that should be part of the specification

Tags: polkadot, pallet, runtime, specs, architecture

We are working on an alternative implementation of the Polkadot protocol, but since the spec is missing a lot of details regarding the Runtime, we rely heavily on the Substrate implementation.

So we want to identify which Substrate pallets (functionality) should be considered as constituting the core of the protocol, the ones that at some point should be generalized and added as part of the spec?

Comment: could you elaborate  more which consensus mechanism you want to use? POA or NPOS

Comment: Currently, we have an implementation with PoA, but let's say we want to support NPoS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pallets needed for staking](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2944/pallets-needed-for-staking)

Comment: Not exactly, but thanks!